# How to select an element inside another element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<td><a href="...">aaa</a></td>

<td><div><a href="...">bbb</a></div></td>

<td><a href="...">ccc</a></td>
```

I need a way to select ONLY the ***a*** inside a ***td*** and NOT inside a ***div*** too.

So in the example above I need to get:

```
<a href="...">aaa</a>
<a href="...">ccc</a>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: As long as the `a` is a direct child of `td`, you can do `td > a { }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target only anchor elements that are children of a `td`. A [**child combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`) matches only the children (direct descendants) of an element.

```css
td > a {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td><a href="">aaa</a></td>
  <td>
    <div><a href="">bbb</a></div>
  </td>
  <td><a href="">ccc</a></td>
</table>
```

A [**descendant combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) (), which targets all descendants (not only the children), would not work because it would also match the anchor in the second `td`.

```css
td a {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td><a href="">aaa</a></td>
  <td>
    <div><a href="">bbb</a></div>
  </td>
  <td><a href="">ccc</a></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select only immediate children by using `>` as so:

`td>a {
    ...some styling
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Using **parent > direct-child** selector

```css
td > a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">aaa</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <a href="#">bbb</a>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="#">ccc</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```